# 2D Heat equation with Initial Data

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have the following 2D heat equation:

$$u_t - \Delta u = e^t$$ where $(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2, t > 0, u(x_1, x_2, 0) = cos(x_1) sin(x_2)$

I am looking to find the general solution $u(x_1, x_2, t)$. I know that it should be the convolution of the heat kernel and the initial data which I'm unsure how to compute

Comment: If you separate variable there is a solution $u=e^{-2t}\cos x_1\sin x_2+e^t-1$.